# WPF dynamic Questionnaire user control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

In WPF I need to have UI like below without code behind. The question will vary for each customer. Question & answer is configurable and it should be loaded dynamically from the database. I require help on how to achieve the problem. I am new to WPF.

[image]

```
CustomerID  Customer Name   Question    Answers    Types
1001    XYZ Customer Sex?   o Male  o Female  o Other   Radio button
1002    ABC Customer Sex?   o Male  o Female  o Other   Radio button
        Movie Type? [] Type 1 [] Type 2 [] Type 3   Checkbox
1003    QWE Enter the description   Plain TextBox   Textbox
        Select Any one  List    Listbox/ combobox
```

Comment: When creating variable of repeated UI then your first candidate is templating. You can define a template identified by datatype. Present an object of that type and it will be templated into your ui. This is how you'd switch out UI for the answers column.

Comment: Hiding repeated content. This could be done with a datatrigger sets Visibility. There's a relativesource binding that allows you to compare to previousData = the last record. You'd then want a converter allows you to compare that to the current row and return Visibility.Collapsed or Visibility.Visible.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596443/how-can-i-build-a-questionnaire-usercontrol-in-xaml-whose-questions-share-the-sa and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457157/how-generatebinding-quiz-in-form-using-wpf-mvvm